# allocating multiple instance of the same class on the same line

Tags: objective-c, object

```
@interface Velocity2 : UIViewController {
UILabel * answerLabel;
UITextField * varA,varB,varC;
```

Is this legal to do or is below the only way to do it?

```
    UITextField * varA;
    UITextField * varB;
    UITextField * varC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Legal:

```
UITextField *varA, *varB, *varC;
```

Comment: May be a technicality, but neither of these answers are allocating anything.

Comment: +1 kubi for also noticing that nothing is getting allocated but just declared.

Comment: What kubi says is very important to keep in mind. A variable is just a place to store a reference to an object so you can talk to the object later. Just creating a variable does not actually create an object for you to talk to any more than carving a mailbox magically causes somebody to retrieve mail from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *varA, *varB, *varC;
```